# Comma delimited values do not display with “foreach”. only one shows up. Why?

Tags: php

This code is not working. I am trying to get a list of feature names. Products in category 12 all have 5 features assigned, but it only shows 1 feature when it prints.

Strangely enough, when I echo **$FeatureName** immediately after the second query (before closing bracket), it echos the 5 items. But when I call **$HTML**, I only get one.

The features from the first query look like this:

```
23,41,68,71,80
```

My code is as follows:

```
$HTML="<table><tr>";

$i=0;
$count=0;
$query="SELECT features FROM products WHERE category='12'";
$res=mysql_query($query);
while(list($features)=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
   $i++;
   $count++;

$features = explode(',' , $features);

foreach($features as $x =>$key) {
$x >0;
       $query="SELECT FeatureName FROM products_features WHERE id='$key'";
       list($FeatureName)=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
}

$HTML.="<td> $FeatureName </td>";

      if(($i%1)==0)
         $HTML.="</tr><tr>";
  }
$HTML.="</tr></table>";
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Regardless of problems with this code, you should normalize your database tables. If you did that, you would be able to simplify this mess into a single query, with trivial logic on the PHP side. Much easier to maintain, more general, and easier to verify correctness.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am a beginner and will look into that. I don't even know what normalizing a database entails. One query would be nice. Thanks again.

Comment: Basically in this case it means not storing more than one value in a single database column. If you _need_ the comma seperated results somewhere else, you can get them back with a group concatenation. You need a product features table which stores one product/feature id pair per row. You get the real results by doing a table join. Also, I feel obligated to mention, as I always do on questions like this: the `mysql_` functions are deprecated; use the mysqli interface or PDO instead.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't like doing it the way I am now really, very cumbersome. I will research and hopefully implement your suggestions. -- edit: yes, features  are in their own table, one per row.

Comment: Don't let it scare you, by the way, that the SQL queries will be a bit more complicated with joins. Let the database do what it was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

You did

```
$HTML.="<td> $FeatureName </td>";
```

outside of the `foreach($features as $x =>$key)` loop. Put it inside to get it work, so:

```
foreach($features as $x =>$key) {
   $query="SELECT FeatureName FROM products_features WHERE id='$key'";
   list($FeatureName)=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
   $HTML.="<td> $FeatureName </td>";
}
```

Comment: thank  you. I was worried about putting there since it's already a loop. But it seems to work. Thank you again.

Comment: @user3141201 You're welcome. If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the thick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have put $HTML out side foreach loop.

Following is corrected code snip for you.

```
$HTML="<table><tr>";

$i=0;
$count=0;
$query="SELECT features FROM products WHERE category='12'";
$res=mysql_query($query);
while(list($features)=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {

$features = explode(',' , $features);

foreach($features as $x =>$key) {

   $i++;
   $count++;

$x >0;
       $query="SELECT FeatureName FROM products_features WHERE id='$key'";
       list($FeatureName)=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
$HTML.="<td> $FeatureName </td>";

      if(($i%1)==0)
         $HTML.="</tr><tr>";
}

  }
$HTML.="</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Thank you Jay. You've answered previous questions for me. I really appreciate the full edit. Everyone is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You append to $HTML outside of the inner loop.